# Laravel 10 Livewire 3.3 nginx 502 bad gateway

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, livewire-3

I am currently facing an issue with Livewire where a 502 Bad Gateway error occurs, and I have identified the root cause. In my Livewire component, I am using dependency injection in the mount method to inject a service (BookingServiceInterface), which, in turn, has a constructor with another injected service.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
    protected $bookingService;

    public function mount(BookingServiceInterface $bookingService, $booking)
    {
        // Some logic using $bookingService
    }
}
```

The BookingServiceInterface has a constructor that injects another service:

```
class BookingService implements BookingServiceInterface
{
    protected $anotherService;

    public function __construct(AnotherServiceInterface $anotherService)
    {
        $this->anotherService = $anotherService;
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

It seems that Livewire might encounter challenges with nested dependency injection, resulting in the 502 error.

I am seeking insights and suggestions on how to address this issue with nested dependency injection in Livewire. Any guidance or alternative approaches to handle dependencies in Livewire components would be highly appreciated. Thank you!